# SQL Server DELETE query performance

Tags: sql-server, delete-row

I've got a simple table and I'm evaluating which is the best way to delete some records from it.

The DELETE query is so simple: `DELETE FROM [dbo].[Badge] WHERE [Id_Operatore] = @SOMEVALUE`

Is there a way to increase performance of this operation?

This is the table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Badge](
    [Id_Badge] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Id_Operatore] [int] NULL,
    [Badge0] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge1] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge2] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge3] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge4] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge5] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge6] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge7] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge8] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge9] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge10] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge11] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge12] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge13] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge14] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge15] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge16] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge17] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge18] [smallint] NULL,
    [Badge19] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Badge]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Badge_FK00] FOREIGN KEY([Id_Operatore])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Operatori] ([ID_Operatore])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Badge] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Badge_FK00]
GO
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table `Badge`? Please do include their DDL too.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index on the foreign key.

The index might be covering, so including all these badges is not a bad idea.

Comment: Something like this? CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_IdOperatore] ON [dbo].[Badge] 
(
 [Id_Operatore] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Yes, and as I wrote above, INCLUDE all badges is not a bad idea, because in that case the index is the cover index and might help in some other situations. The index will not be a fat index. All these badges are the type of smallint.

Answer (score 0):

Create a clustered (preferred) or nonclustered index on [Id_Operatore].

"Clustered" keeps the data physical by each other.
This reduces the IO on delete.